# Setting values of a tensor based on given indices of corresponding rows using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I've got a tensor `A` with shape `(M, N)`, and have another tensor `B` with shape `(M, P)` and with values of given indices in corresponding rows of `A`. Now I would like to set the values of `A` with corresponding indices in `B` to `0`.

For example:

```py
In[1]: import torch
       A = torch.tensor([range(1,11), range(1,11), range(1,11)])
       A
Out[1]: 
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

```py
In[2]: B = torch.tensor([[1,2], [2,3], [3,5]])
       B
Out[2]: 
tensor([[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 5]])
```

The objective is to set the value of the element with index `1,2` in the first row, `2,3` in the second row, and `3,5` in the third row of `A` to `0`, i.e., setting `A` to

```py
tensor([[ 1,  0,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  0,  0,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  0,  5,  0,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

I have applied row by row for loop, and also tried `scatter`:

```py
zeros = torch.zeros(A.shape, dtype=torch.float).to("cuda")
A = A.scatter_(1, B, zeros)
```

The two methods work fine, but all give quite poor performance. Actually, I infer that some efficient approach should exist based on an error before. I initially used `A[:, B] = 0`. This would set all the indices of appeared in `B` to `0`, regardless of the row. However, the training speed improved drastically when doing `A[:, B] = 0`.

Is there any way to implement this more efficiently?

Comment: Are you sure `scatter_` is slow, can you prove it? That should be the go-to method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what i would do:

```
import torch
A = torch.tensor([range(1,11), range(1,11), range(1,11)])
B = torch.tensor([[1,2], [2,3], [3,5]])
r, c = B.shape
idx0 = torch.arange(r).reshape(-1, 1).repeat(1, c).flatten()
idx1 = B.flatten()
A[idx0, idx1] = 0
```

output:

```
A = 
tensor([[ 1,  0,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  0,  0,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  0,  5,  0,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: You could use `idx0 = torch.arange(r).repeat_interleave(c)` instead.